# Pigeon Hole Principle x

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

How many different numbers must be selected from the first 25 positive integers to be certain that at least one of them will be twice the other ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You will get a lot more help and a lot fewer down votes is you show that you have made an effort to solve the problem yourself.  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: My answer was 18. First, count the odd numbers from 1 to 25, then eliminate those even ones from 24 downwards. Just wondering I was wrong

Comment: Final answer - 17.

Comment: 13 odd integers from 1 to 25, then 4, 16, 20, 24, that makes 17+1 = 18

Comment: Just a tip.  You ought to put your reasoning in the body of the question, not in the comments.  Many people don't read the comments when browsing questions, and if they see no more than you have written, they will vote to close the question and move on.  You'll find lots of helpful people on this site, but you have to meet them halfway.  (By the way, a vote to close isn't a personal attack; it's just quality control.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it.  Group the integers we get by doubling

A:$1,2,4,8,16$

B:$3,6,12,24$

C:$5,10,20$

D:$7,14$

E:$9,18$

F:$11,22$

We have $7$ odd numbers from $13$ to $25$ not included and we can take them all.  We can take $1$ each from groups $F$, $E$, and $D$, $2$ each from groups $C$ and $B$ and $3$ from group $A$ giving $17$ at most with no doubles, so if we choose 18, we are certain of having a double.

Comment: That would make 17 integers not twice of each other. Need to add 1 more to have one twice the other ? in other words, need to have 18 ?

Comment: Put another way: partition $\{1,\dots, 25\}$ into groups of the form $\{a\cdot2^k\}$, where $a$ is odd. There are $13$ such groups, one for each odd number on $\{1,\dots, 25\}$. For each group $G$, you can alternate between picking a number (starting from the lowest, odd one) and not picking its double; hence, you'll be able to pick $\lceil |G|/2\rceil$ numbers from each group. This is the most you can do without infringing on the double rule. Adding any one number will result in there being a guaranteed double pair, and yields the answer.

Comment: @MarcusYap Yes, you're right.  I forgot the question!

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing saulspatz' answer:
partition $\{1,\dots, n\}$ into groups of the form $G_a=\{a\cdot2^k\}$, where $a$ is odd.
There are $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ such groups, one for each odd number on $\{1,\dots, n\}$.

On each group $G_a$, we can alternate between picking a number $($starting from $a)$ and not picking its double.
In this way, we'll be able to pick $\lceil |G_a|/2\rceil$ numbers from each group.
This is the most we can do without infringing on the double rule.
Adding any one number will result in there being a guaranteed double pair, and yields the answer.

The answer therefore has the form

$$1+\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil n/2 \rceil}\left\lceil \frac{\left|G_{2k-1}\right|}2 \right\rceil.$$

We can calculate $\left|G_{2k-1}\right|$.
We have $G_a = \{a\cdot 2^k\,|\,k=0,\dots, k_a\}$ where $k_a$ is the maximum integer $k$ such that $a\cdot 2^k \leq n$.
It follows that

$$k\leq \log_2(n/a) \implies k_a = \left\lfloor\log_2(n/a)\right\rfloor$$

and hence $|G_a| = 1+ \left\lfloor\log_2(n/a)\right\rfloor$.
Therefore, the answer is

\begin{align}
1+\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil n/2 \rceil}\left\lceil \frac{1+ \left\lfloor\log_2\left(\frac{n}{2k-1}\right)\right\rfloor}2 \right\rceil
&=
1+\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil n/2 \rceil}\left\lceil \frac{ \left\lfloor1+\log_2\left(\frac{n}{2k-1}\right)\right\rfloor}2 \right\rceil
\\&=
1+\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil n/2 \rceil}\left\lceil \frac{ \left\lfloor \log_2(2)+\log_2\left(\frac{n}{2k-1}\right)\right\rfloor}2 \right\rceil
\\&=
1+\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil n/2 \rceil}\left\lceil \frac{ \left\lfloor \log_2\left(\frac{2n}{2k-1}\right)\right\rfloor}2 \right\rceil
\end{align}

You can check that for $n=25$ this yields the answer of $18$, [as expected](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+Sum%5Bceil(floor(log_2(50%2F(2k-1)))%2F2),+%7Bk,1,13%7D%5D).
Curiously, this is consistently ***very*** close to $\frac23n$ for large $n$.
I don't quite know why.

---

EDIT: Okay, I got a convincing heuristic (convincing to me, at least) as to why the answer is close to $\frac23n$.
In keeping with the notation above, for each value of $k=0,2,4,\dots$ $($the values of $k$ we don't skip when building a maximal set without a double pair$)$, we will count the number of values $a$ for which $k_a \geq k$.
We hence have:

\begin{align}
\sum_{j\geq 0}\, |\{a\,:\, a \,\text{ is odd and }\, k_{a}\geq 2j\}|
&=
\sum_{j\geq 0}\, |\{a\,:\, a \,\text{ is odd and }\, a\leq n/2^{2j}\}|
\\&\simeq
\frac12\,\sum_{j\geq 0}\, |\{a\,:\, a\leq n/2^{2j}\}|
\\&\simeq
\frac12\,\sum_{j\geq 0}\, \frac{n}{4^{j}}
\\&=
\frac{n}2\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac14} = \frac{n}2 \cdot \frac43 = \frac23n
\end{align}